# Persistent settings in MapInfo programs

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have a couple of MapInfo programs that use external EXEs for some functionality (e.g. ogr2ogr for layer conversion and OV2 Tools for satnav data output).

In my programs I would like to have a settings dialog where you set the location of these EXEs and then *somehow* store these so that they are remembered even after Mapinfo has been closed down.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the path in a text file which your program then reads when you start the tool up.

For example, the Named Views tool stores data in a xml document at C:\Documents and Settings\User Name\Application Data\MapInfo\MapInfo\nviews.xml

Answer (score 0):

Like above, just use a properties file, that is overwritten with the last known exe you've typed in, and pre populates a dialogue.  Can be any format.  You then open read/write and close it just like any text file.